# Metacity Tahrballed After Upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, metacity

I've just upgraded from Precise to Trusty, and now when I log in to Metacity I have no top bar or status bar, and no working keyboard shortcuts. The mouse works, but aside from a half-dozen desktop icons there's nothing to click on.

Can anyone help walk me through the process of getting Metacity working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted this question to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2307177) where it was answered by moderator Frogs hair. His first solution (which had no appreciable effect, but is included here for completeness) was

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
```

His second solution (which worked) was one which he apparently found here on Ask Ubuntu:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-panel.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
```

He did not provide a link to the post, and says the post included no explanation, so I would be interested if anyone can tell me what this command did for me and why.